# How to deploy APK from TFS to Google Play?

Tags: android, tfs, google-play, continuous-deployment, azure-devops

I'm in the research phase of a native Android application side project for which I would like to utilize Android Studio and Visual Studio Online (TFS). The app will also have web service portion (WCF/WebAPI TBD) written in .Net.

So far I've found how to integrate TFS with Android Studio and build the package using Maven, but am hung up on how to automate the package deployment from TFS to Goole Play.

Is it possible to have TFS deploy to Google Play?

- If so, how do I configure TFS to do this?
- If not, is there an alternative ALM I should use that would meet all these requirements (SCCM, planning, building, testing, deployment to website and Google Play)?

**Note**: I may want to monetize this so it will be closed source.

Comment: Which build system are you using? vNext or XAML?

Comment: Check this task https://github.com/lostintangent/vso-extension-android/tree/master/vso-task-google-play

Comment: @Cece-MSFT Can you add an answer with steps on how to configure the build too? I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To upload an existing task to VSO, you need to use the “[TFS Cross Platform Command Line](https://github.com/Microsoft/tfs-cli)”, also known as TFX.

Instructions are in the [README.md](https://github.com/Microsoft/tfs-cli/blob/master/README.md) at the GitHub. Basically:

- Install Node.JS from the Node website.
- Run at the command-line: `npm install –g tfx-cli`
- Run tfx login and enter your collection url (probably
  https://youraccount.visualstudio.com) and your [personal access token](http://roadtoalm.com/2015/07/22/using-personal-access-tokens-to-access-visual-studio-online/)
- Run `tfx upload <folder>` to upload your task.
- Run `tfx delete <GUID>` to delete your task. TFX does not overwrite, so
  you’ll need to delete before uploading again.

Check this blog: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-delivery/writing-build-vnext-tasks-for-visual-studio-online/

Then you can add [this task](https://github.com/lostintangent/vso-extension-android) in your build steps in vNext build to automate deployment from Visual Studio Online to Google Play.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to verify yet but I'll mark as answer for the time being. Thank you!